# Kubernetes limit nvdia GPU

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node with 2 gpu on it, and I deploy two containers each with 1 gpu limit
resources:
limits:
nvidia.com/gpu: 1

It works well with nvidia official container . However with my container I can see 2 gpu inside each container

So the resources limits only works during scheduling which I can only deploy two pods with gpu limits 1.

I am expecting inside the container it can only use 1 gpu which matches the resource limit.

Is it sth to do with the container? I thought it should be controlled on the kubernetes level?

Any suggestions?

Regards
David

Comment: can you provide further info ? the yaml file/s

Comment: also have you deployed the NVIDIA plugin ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#deploying-nvidia-gpu-device-plugin Once installed kubernetes exposes nvidia.com/gpu as a schedulable resource

Comment: Yes Nvidia plugin installed. Adding some further notice. I found it is related to Env param NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES Inside my container I found it’s all while inside the nvidia/cuda

Comment: Wonder how k8s pass the value to NVIDIA VISIBLE DEVICES and why my container still is the default value all while the Nvidia cuda container got updated to the GPU id

Comment: Got the cause. In kubernetes we have privileges as true, so that the resources limits Not working